# Visual Works Smalltalk class not getting activated

Tags: visualworks

I have created a class in visual works smalltalk, added a method (for example: list) but when I called it in workspace it shows error like message not understood #list.

Thank You in Advance.

Comment: Posting your code snippet and the error log will allow users to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure you sent the message to the class and not to the instance, so you need to send #new first.

If you create a Class like "Foo" and add an instance method like "bar", you need to evaluate:

```
Foo new bar
```